# kusto - coalesce and next - why not just use next for everything?

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql

I have the following two queries which i am running on the azure kusto online query terminal

(available at this link - https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples )

```
//okay this is lag related code.
//but we need to serialize first in some way, in other words sort it
StormEvents
| order by StartTime | extend LaggedOutput = next( State,2,"NOTHING FOUND") | project State,LaggedOutput;
//lets try coalasce 
//next inside the coalesce returns a empty string and that is replaced with our replacement.
//note : I think we can forgo coalesce completely because next
//already has a default value.
StormEvents
| order by StartTime | project coalesce(next(State,2,""),"COALSESCE");
```

So, my question is, why bother with coalesce at all? next() already provides a default value that I can apply in this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the scenario you provided, the answer is yes: you can remove the `coalesce` from the **2nd query**, and just use `next` operator with a default value like below(for the 2nd query):

```
StormEvents
| order by StartTime 
| project next(State,2,"COALSESCE")
```

the output is same as using `project coalesce(next(State,2,""),"COALSESCE")`.

**But** for other scenarios, like I want to get a **non-null value** from several values, sample like below:

```
print result=coalesce(tolong("not a number"), tolong("42"), 33)
```

and here, we can only use the `coalesce` operator to get **the first non-null value** => 42. This is the scenario the `next` operator cannot cover.